# First LDAP search of the day is very slow, but all others are quick? Looking to boost Performance and Diagnose this issue

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, connection-pooling

Using LdapContext to perform a search against an AD server. All my requests are using simple auth type. Have encountered an issue where the first search is slow, but all subsequent searches are fast. Ive added logging and determined that it is the search that is taking a long time (20+ seconds).

However, this only occurs on the first search, subsequent searches are very quick.

After I initially encountered this issue, I saw a post indicating I should change the line

`env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");`
to
`env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "ignore");`

This did not solve the issue.

I then did further research into LDAP Connection Pooling. I discovered that by default, connections with a simple auth type are pooled and not removed until garbage collected by java. I suspected this may be the issue, so I added the following line to see if with pooling disabled, if every connection request and search would take a longer time than typical.

`env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool", "false");`

This did not work, was still seeing fast connections after applying this change, which is not the behavior I would expect.

Additionally, I set a time limit of 3000 on my search controls. Was under the impression that this is in Milliseconds, so I'm not sure how this search is taking 20+ seconds if there is a limitation of 3 seconds.

```
    Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, request.getLdapUrl());
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, request.getLdapUserPrincipal());
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, request.getLdapCredentials());
    env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "ignore");
    env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool", "false");
    LdapContext ctx = null;
    try
    {
      LOG.info("Starting Connection Time in Millis: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
        LOG.info("FINISHING Connection Time in Millis: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
        searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        searchControls.setTimeLimit(3000);
        ctx.setRequestControls(null);
        LOG.info("Starting Search Time in Millis: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        NamingEnumeration<?> namingEnum = ctx.search("ou=Users", "(CN=" + staffVerifyRequest.getIDToVerify() +")", searchControls);

        while (namingEnum.hasMore())
        {
            SearchResult result = (SearchResult) namingEnum.next();
        }
        LOG.info("Ending Search Time in Millis: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        ctx.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
```

I would just like the search to perform quickly every time rather than every time EXCEPT the first. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It could still be connection pooling. Maybe monitor the connections using a tool on the OS (for example, in Windows I use Process Explorer to monitor connections) and see if the connection stays alive and is reused for the next requests. That would tell you if *setting up the connection* is the problem.

Comment: @GabrielLuci its possible for connections to pool even when I explicitly set it to false?

Comment: I don't know :) I'm not a Java developer (although I do understand AD). But I do know that sometimes things don't work as expected.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look using Process Explorer. Thank you

Comment: Directory services are usually using caches to reduce the IOs and optimize repeated queries. This can explain why the first one is slow and not the following ones. If that's really the reason, there is no way to optimize the first request, apart from running on a better hardware.

Comment: @LudovicPoitou do you know if there is a certain frequency with which the caching occurs? My thinking is that if I ping the Directory with an arbitrary request every once in a while, then the cache will be "warmed up" so to speak

Comment: Caches strategy differ from server to server. Your first request is your ping :)